# Regular Expression to accept the number with given specific set

Tags: java, regex, numbers

I am writing a sample program in which a number should accept if and only if it contains `1,2,3,4` digits in it irrespective of its length.

**Example**

**Should Accept**

```
123
1234
122334444111222
133333333333322222244444
```

**Should not Accept**

```
0123
8123
451233441122
12345
12333333335
12321321367
```

To achieve the above I written a regx (regular expression) `"[1-4]+\\d"`

The above regx expression is not checking the last digit. It is accepting the number ends with 5,6,7,8,9,0.

Example

**Accepting**

```
125
2345
123213213232135
1232132132135
1232132132136
1232132132137
1232132132138
```

**Not accepting**

```
1232321355
232321355
21321360
123278
```

Please any one explain the reason why it is not checking the last digit so that it helps in further exploration. and also good working expression to do the same.

Thanks in Advance

**Note**: *this is in java*

Comment: I guess because it must accept only digit 'd', and double slash because java won't accept single slash (throws compile time error).

Comment: should not accept: `12345 12333333335` ? hm

Comment: No it should not spaces are not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `\\d` at the end, which matches any digit.  Leave that part out:

```
^[1-4]+$
```

Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/ydYmT5oeZf

Comment: The `^` and `$` are not necessary when it is used with `String.matches`

Comment: it is working good. Thanks for the valuable answer and the demo.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify that the regular expression has to cover the whole string:

```
^[1-4]+$
```

By default a regular expression searches if there is any match within the given input. `^` tells the engine that the match should start at the beginning and `$` that it should end at the last character.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html